How does this canonical transformation on a Schwarzschild black hole work?
In this paper "Holography of the Photon Ring" the authors use a canonical transformation in section 2.4 in eqs. (2.52)-(2.55).
It is basically a transformation from spherical coordinates for a Schwarzschild black hole on a reduced phase space $(r, \phi, p_r, p_\phi)$ to coordinates in which the symmetries are very visible $(T, \Phi, H, L)$ where $H$ and $L$ are the conserved quantities related to the stationarity and axial symmetry, while $T$ and $\Phi$ are in essence Hamilton's equations.
From Hamilton's equations the authors derive
\begin{equation}\label{eq:prSchw}
    p_r(r, H, L) = \pm_r \frac{\sqrt{\mathcal{R}(r)}}{r^2 - 2Mr}, \qquad  \qquad \mathcal{R}(r) = r^4H^2 - \left(r^2-2Mr\right)L^2.
\end{equation}
from which it is computed that
\begin{align}
    d T &= \frac{Hr^4}{\left(r^2-2Mr\right)\sqrt{\mathcal{R}(r)}} d r \\
    d \Phi &= d \phi -  \frac{L}{\sqrt{\mathcal{R}(r)}} d r.
\end{align}
The authors claim that this defines a canonical transformation.
However I am quite confused on how this makes sense as these expressions are not closed in the sense that $d^2T \neq 0$ and $d^2 \Phi \neq 0$, because of the $p_r$ and $p_\phi$ dependence in the expressions for $H$ and $L$.
I understand that $H$ and $L$ are conserved along geodesic motion, however I don't understand why this can be used in doing the canonical transformation.


We restrict phase space to the equatorial plane $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $p_{\theta}=0$.

We consider the Schwarzschild solution
$$\begin{align} ds^2~=~&-f(r)dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{f(r)}+r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2)\cr~=~&-f(r)dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{f(r)}+r^2 d\phi^2.\tag{2.1}\end{align} $$

The Lagrangian for the null geodesics is standard.

We impose that the 4-momentum is null
$$\begin{align} 0~=~&-m^2~=~p_{\mu}g^{\mu\nu}p_{\nu}\cr
~=~&-\frac{p_t^2}{f(r)}+f(r)p_r^2 +\frac{p_{\theta}^2}{r^2}+\frac{p_{\phi}^2}{r^2\sin^2\theta}\cr
~=~&-\frac{p_t^2}{f(r)}+f(r)p_r^2 +\frac{p_{\phi}^2}{r^2},\end{align}
 $$
which should be viewed as a definition of the radial momentum
$$ p_r(r,p_t,p_{\phi})~:=~\sqrt{\frac{\cal W}{f(r)}}, \qquad {\cal W}~:=~\frac{p_t^2}{f(r)}-\frac{p_{\phi}^2}{r^2}. $$

The variables $t$ and $\phi$ are cyclic, and hence $p_t$ and $p_{\phi}$ are COM.
We will consider a 4-dimensional mini phase space with fundamental variables $(r,\phi,p_t,p_{\phi})$.

Define radial antiderivative $$I(\cdot)~:=~\left.\int_{r_{\ast}}^r\! \mathrm{d}r(\cdot)\right|_{p_t,p_{\phi},\phi},$$
where $r_{\ast}$ is a radial reference point.
Define restricted exterior derivative
$$ \mathrm{d}_|~:=~\mathrm{d} - \mathrm{d}r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}~=~\mathrm{d}p_t\frac{\partial}{\partial p_t}+\mathrm{d}p_{\phi}\frac{\partial}{\partial p_{\phi}}+\mathrm{d}\phi\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}. $$
Note that $I$ and $\mathrm{d}_|$ commute.

Define functions
$$ \begin{align} g(r,p_t,p_{\phi})~:=~&\frac{\partial p_r}{\partial p_t}~=~\frac{p_t}{f^2p_r}, \cr
 e(r,p_t,p_{\phi})~:=~&-\frac{\partial p_r}{\partial p_{\phi}}~=~\frac{p_{\phi}}{r^2fp_r}.\end{align} $$
Note that since $p_r$ is a homogeneous function of the momenta $(p_t,p_{\phi})$ with weight 1, we have
$$ p_r~=~\left(p_t\frac{\partial }{\partial p_t}+p_{\phi}\frac{\partial }{\partial p_{\phi}}\right)p_r~=~p_tg-p_{\phi}e .$$

Define 1-forms
$$ \begin{align} \tau~:=~&g\mathrm{d}r, \cr
\eta~:=~&e\mathrm{d}r. 
\end{align} $$
Then
$$ p_r\mathrm{d}r~=~p_t\tau-p_{\phi}\eta.$$

Define new coordinates
$$ \begin{align}  T(r,p_t,p_{\phi})~:=~&I(g)~=~\int_{r_{\ast}}^r\! \tau, \cr
\phi-\Phi(r,\phi,p_t,p_{\phi}) ~:=~&I(e)~=~\int_{r_{\ast}}^r\! \eta. 
\end{align} $$
Then
$$ \begin{align}  \mathrm{d}T~=~&\tau+I(\mathrm{d}_|g) , \cr
\mathrm{d}\phi-\mathrm{d}\Phi ~=~&\eta+I(\mathrm{d}_|e) . 
\end{align} $$
Therefore we may identify
$$ \begin{align}  \mathrm{d}T~\approx~&\tau , \cr
\mathrm{d}\phi-\mathrm{d}\Phi ~\approx~&\eta , 
\end{align} $$
along a geodesic where $\mathrm{d}p_t\approx 0\approx\mathrm{d}p_{\phi}$.

Let us consider the tautological symplectic potential 1-form
$$ \begin{align} \vartheta~:=~&p_r\mathrm{d}r +p_{\phi}\mathrm{d}\phi\cr ~=~&p_t\tau-p_{\phi}\eta+p_{\phi}\mathrm{d}\phi\cr 
~=~& p_t\mathrm{d}T+p_{\phi}\mathrm{d}\Phi-I\left(p_t\mathrm{d}_|g-p_{\phi}\mathrm{d}_|e\right)\cr
~=~& p_t\mathrm{d}T+p_{\phi}\mathrm{d}\Phi-I\left(\mathrm{d}_| (p_tg-p_{\phi}e)-g\mathrm{d}_|p_t+e\mathrm{d}_|p_{\phi}\right)\cr  
~=~& p_t\mathrm{d}T+p_{\phi}\mathrm{d}\Phi-I\left(\mathrm{d}_| p_r-\frac{\partial p_r}{\partial p_t}\mathrm{d}p_t-\frac{\partial p_r}{\partial p_{\phi}}\mathrm{d}p_{\phi}\right)\cr 
~=~& p_t\mathrm{d}T+p_{\phi}\mathrm{d}\Phi, \end{align} \tag{2.55}$$
which shows that
$$(r,\phi;p_r,p_{\phi}) \quad\longrightarrow\quad(T,\Phi;p_t,p_{\phi}) $$
is a symplectomorphism in the mini phase space.


References:

S. Hadar, D. Kapec, A. Lupsasca  & A. Strominger, Holography of the Photon Ring, arXiv:2205.05064; section 2.4.


Wonderful answer! I just have a few questions: (1) the step in 9. where you say we can identify $dT$ and $d\Phi$ as $\tau$ and $\eta$ along a geodesic seems strange to me. Why do we lose the second term? (2) Does the differential operator $d$ also commute with both $I$ and $d_\vert$?

(1) I updated the answer. (2) No, essentially because integration and differentiation do not commute due to a possible integration constant.

(1) still confuses me because $dp_t \approx 0$ would imply that the symplectomorphism does not work right? Or is the statement more like  $dp_t \approx 0$ is an informal way to see this?  (2) So if i understand correctly, the first expressions in 9. for $dT$ and $d\Phi$ obey $d^2 T = d^2\Phi = 0$?

(1) That is observed but not used anywhere in the answer, in particular not in section 10. (2) Yes.

(1) In 9. it is. This is precisely where my confusion stemmed from! But I guess the formal expression is precisely the first ones you give for $dT$ and $d\Phi$.
